# NodeJS HapiJS with OAUTH2 and Salesforce (force.com)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, salesforce, hapi.js

Hello bell / hapi developers and/or experts... thank you in advance for any advice...  I'm trying to complete a forcedotcom strategy (salesforce) for oauth, and it is nearly working, and I can't find any documentation for the error.

I get an error "[Error: Failed obtaining custom access token]"

My app properly redirects to salesforce, prompts for login on Salesforce domain, authenticates, and properly returns back to the callback URL, however, the callback url route/controller, fails because "isAuthenticated" is false, but I can see in the request, the URL returned from salesforce to the callback contains a "code" parameter (the auth access token, and a "state" value.)

Here is my strategy

```js
// Register bell with the server
server.register(require('bell'), function(err) {
  server.auth.strategy('forcedotcom', 'bell', {
    provider: {
      protocol: 'oauth2',
      useParamsAuth: false,
      auth: config.forcedotcom.authURL,
      token: config.forcedotcom.tokenURL
    },
    isSecure: false,
    clientId: config.forcedotcom.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.forcedotcom.clientSecret,
    password: config.sessionCookie.sessionSecret,
    location: config.forcedotcom.callbackURL
  });
});
```

Here is the callback route (specified in the config of callbackURL

```js
server.route({
  method: ['GET', 'POST'],
  path: '/auth/forcedotcom/callback',
  config: {
    auth: {
      strategy: 'forcedotcom',
      mode: 'try'
    },
    handler: function(request, reply) {
      console.warn('request', request, 'reply', reply);
      if (!request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
        return reply('Authentication failed due to: ' + request.auth.error.message);
      }

      return reply.redirect('/');
    }
  }
});
```

Any direction would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: with the help of a developer from hapi, we are seeing a 400 from salesforce on the second call / token request... another post unrelated to hapi solved this by uri decoding the oauth code from salesforce (first response), before sending to the token callback.   I don't know how to do this with hapi, but we are getting closer.  [similar-but-different-problem-resolved](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43878/400-bad-request-in-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set `useParamAuth` to `true`. Salesforce requires the `client_secret` and `client_id` to be query parameters instead of headers.

You could also try this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-salesforce-auth-suite, which includes signrequest auth as well as oauth.

Comment: This was part of the problem, the other part, I ashamed to say was the cookie SSL setting, testing in localhost with SSL cookie on and browsing from http was not setting the cookie properly. :(